# Want to replace a matched word with incremental variable value

Tags: bash, sed

```
Input File :
Name
Den
Surname
Addr
Den
Number
Pin
Den
```

```
Output File :
Name
Den
1
Surname
Addr
Den
2
Number
Pin
Den 
3
```

So i want to match Den as pattern and add new line below Den having  number. But with every match of Den the new number added should be incremented.

Comment: I do not understand, could you reformat your post to cleanly post the expected output _and input_ into code blocks with `\n` replaced with an actual newline? What is the input? What should the output be? How is "expected output" generated? What is the input?

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep` to produce line numbers for `sed` is decidedly an antipattern - `sed` can certainly find the regex matches on its own. But this problem seems more suitable for Awk.

```sh
awk '{ while(/den/ && sub("den", "ten\n" ++a));; print }' file
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/4pGe9l

GNU `sed` has an `e` flag which lets you evaluate shell expressions inside `sed` but it's not portable; I would actually regard the requirement to solve this in `sed` as misdirected in any case.

Comment: note that the variable will be incremented even if a line did not match `den`... `perl -pe 's/den/"ten\n" . ++$c/ge'` would fix that

Comment: or `awk '{ while(/den/ && sub("den", "ten\n" ++a));; print }'`

Comment: Isn't there a pure sed based solution without awk

Comment: Why do you think there should be? `sed` doesn't have any built in variables or any math support; you will have to depend on some external utility anyway.

Comment: A `sed` solution without `awk` could be something like `for ((i=1;grep -q ten file;i++)) do  sed_replacing_one_occurance_with_$i; done` but that would be a terrible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use "den" as the record separator and the increasing recordnumber as the increment:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="den"; ORS=""} NR>1 {printf "ten\n" NR-1} 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code:

```
 echo 'For eg first den will be replaced with ten then second den with ten and so on.' |
 # replace "ten" with a "ten" followed a newline and a hash
 sed 's/ten/&\n#/g' |
 # Replace leading hash with a number
 # After each successfull replacement increment number
 awk '{ if (sub(/^#/, i + 1)) i++; } 1'
```

outputs:

```
For eg first den will be replaced with ten
1 then second den with ten
2 and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved

```
COUNTER=1
while [ $COUNTER -le "$(sed -n '/Den/p' file | wc -l)" ];
do
var="$(cat -n file | sed -n '/Den/p'  | awk '{$1=$1};1' | cut -f1 -d ' ' | sed -n ""$(echo "$COUNTER")"p")" && sed ""$(echo "$var")"s/Den/Den\n"$(echo "$COUNTER")"/" file -i && let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
done
```